# Generating secured output stream using security token for wowza

Tags: php, security, wowza

We configured wowza server by following this: 
https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?578-How-to-configure-security-using-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-Manager

Then we generate the authenticate URL for streaming by this php code:

```
//Connect with wowza output steam when SHA-256 security token applied:

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');//set the time zone if server time-zone is not correct 

$wowza_serverip = "103.248.14.30"; // your ip/host 
$wowzatoken = 'wowzatoken'; 

$wowzastart = 0; 
$validity = 1800; // validity in seconds 
$wowzaend = strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i')) + $validity; 
$secret = "7a97766ef659050"; // your secret 
$stream_name = "live/myStream";// your stream myStream is default steaming 

$hashstr = hash('sha256', $stream_name.'?'.$secret.'&amp;'.$wowzatoken.'endtime='.$wowzaend.'&amp;'.$wowzatoken.'starttime='.$wowzastart.'', true); 
$usableHash = strtr(base64_encode($hashstr), '+/', '-_'); 

$url = "rtmp://".$wowza_serverip.":1935/live/myStream?".$wowzatoken."endtime=".$wowzaend."&amp;".$wowzatoken."starttime=".$wowzastart."&amp;".$wowzatoken."hash=".$usableHash.""; 
$iurl = $wowza_serverip.":1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8?".$wowzatoken."endtime=".$wowzaend."&amp;".$wowzatoken."starttime=".$wowzastart."&amp;".$wowzatoken."hash=".$usableHash."";
```

This code can generate secured url to get output stream from wowza. I worked with this code in ***September, 2015*** and it worked perfectly(latest version of wowza on that time! v: 4.3.0 may be).

But unfortunately now generated url can not fetch stream from wowza. And wowza sending a response "**SecurityToken Failure**". We are using latest wowza server (version: 4.6.0).

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: According to wowza support team: This is a known bug (RTMP & RSTP) for version: 4.6.0!

Comment: ...are you supposed to be hashing `&amp;` instead of `&`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, according the comments, this is the result of a bug in the wowza software rather than a general programming question.